# How does the compiler know to return the right type?

Tags: type-inference, elm, type-theory

I have the following code, that I do not understand:

```
type Msg
    = Left | Right


content : Html Msg
content =
    p [] []
```

The type signature of `p`:

```
p : List (Attribute msg) -> List (Html msg) -> Html msg
```

The question is, why `p` can return the type of `Msg` in the `content` function.  I know that `Html msg` and `msg`  can any variable but it does not return either `Left` or `Right`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will take a shot at this (not particularly trained in ML languages or Lambda calculus, and worked with '{}' carrying languages for far too long, so some of my vocabulary may be off):

(1) `Msg` is a type that specializes to either `Left` or `Right`

(2) `content` is a value of type `Html(Msg)`

(3) `content` has value `p [] []`

Let's evaluate `content` ...

(4) `p` is a function of type `p : List (Attribute msg) -> List (Html msg) -> Html msg`

In the expression above `msg` is a type variable, we could also write, less confusingly:

(4a) `p` is a function of type `p : List (Attribute xtype) -> List (Html xtype) -> Html xtype`

In Java syntax that would be something like

(4x) `p` is a function of type `p<XType> : List (Attribute<XType>) -> List (Html<XType>) -> Html<XType>`

So we have the following constraint on `p [] []`:

- It is of type `p : List (Attribute xtype) -> List (Html xtype) -> Html xtype`
- It resolves to type `Html Msg`

this immediately tells us that unknown type `xtype` must actually be type `Msg`:

(5) `p : List (Attribute Msg) -> List (Html Msg) -> Html Msg`

The first argument to `p` is `[]`. According to the constrained signature above, the type of that expression must be `List (Attribute Msg)`. No problem with that, the elm type checking theorem proving engine lets this through.

The second argument to `p` is `[]`. According to the constrained signature above, the type of that expression must be `List (Html Msg)`. No problem with that either.

- Thus, you can invoke `p` with `[] []`.
- Whatever it resolves to will be of type `Html Msg`.

How is that possible if `p` doesn't know much about `Msg`?

Invoke mathematical constraint-based thinking and conclude that `p [] []` must resolve to a value of type `Html x` for every type `x`. This is only possible if it resolves to a value that does not vary in `x` - a constant completely independent of `x`. Therefore `p [] []` resolves to some trivial value. However the [poodle's core](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/des_Pudels_Kern) of the mathematical assertion:

`p : List (Attribute msg) -> List (Html msg) -> Html msg`

is that `p` is something that takes stuff containing values of type `msg` and returns stuff containing values of type `msg`, maybe trivially so if `p` always returns a constant completely not involving anything of type `msg`. It will keep any `msg` as it was (because it has not been given any function transforming `msg`), just shift them around somehow.

See also: ["Theorems for Free!"](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~dreyer/tor/papers/wadler.pdf) by Philp Wadler, 1989 for going deeper into this. Wadler starts off with this:

[image: Text Extract of Theorems for Free!]

Answer (score 0):

Now the `Html` type is such a low level type that it is not actually defined with Elm language. But for the purpose of this question let's imagine that `Html` is defined as

```
type Html msg
  = HtmlWithMessage HtmlNodes msg
  | HtmlWithoutMessage HtmlNodes
```

where `HtmlNodes` would be some type representing the actual html being returned.

Now when you define `Msg` as `type Msg = Left | Right`, then type `Html Msg` can have three possible values:

1. `HtmlWithMessage HtmlNodes Left`
2. `HtmlWithMessage HtmlNodes Right`
3. `HtmlWithoutMessage HtmlNodes`

And since there is no message in `p`, it would return `HtmlWithoutMessage HtmlNodes`.

> The question is, why `p` can return the type of `Msg` in the `content` function. I know that `Html msg` and `msg` can any variable but it does not return either `Left` or `Right`.

`p` is not returning type of `Msg`, but type of `Html` which has type parameter `msg`. The type is not required to use the type parameter in all of its possible values and so can include values which don't use type parameter at all, like `HtmlWithoutMessage HtmlNodes`.